# Difference between set autocommit=0 and set session transaction isolation level REPEATABLE READ;start transaction;?

Tags: mysql, transactions, isolation-level

It is mentioned [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html) that default isolation level for any transaction in innodb is repeatable read.
In the same link above it is also mention that if I do set autocommit=0 then session always have transaction open.
Now My undersatnding is if I do

```
set session transaction isolation level REPEATABLE READ;

start transaction;

DML(insert, update, delete) queries

commit;
```

and

```
 set autocommit=0;

    DML(insert, update, delete) queries

    commit;
```

Both should do the same, should run in repeatable read isolation level. I need to do commit or rollback in the end.

But as I use them for lot of queries the first one take lot of time and second one takes very little time. So clearly they aren't same. What I am missing? what is the default isolation level of transaction while auto commit is set to 0? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:I got the answer of what is default isolation level if I do set autocommit=0;(Thanks to kostja) It can be seen from **show variables like "%isolation";** But I am yet to find out why first one is slower.

Answer (score 1):

Setting autocommit in the session doesn't change it globally.
Sure it's not the case?

Answering your question, transaction isolation level doesn't depend on autocommit.

Comment: But I need to set autocommit=0 for my session only. I need to run queries in single session, I don't see how it is related to my question.

Comment: It's hard to say where you run the query based on your question. Please update the question and this possibility could be wed out.
The second question is where the transaction ends. set autocommit = 0 will stop autocommit, so you may end up with a very long transaction that contains hundreds of statements. Sure it's not the case?

Comment: I edited my question. I am firing commit in the end of my all the queries to I guess both the transaction have same number of queries to execute. Difference is in isolation level I guess. But it is just a guess.

Comment: If you run every query over a client-server app, an extra start transaction statement may add an extra network round-trip. There may be some work done when executing "start transaction" or "set transaction isolation level statements", which is also a little extra. But neither behaviour nor performance of your queries should change based on the way the transaction is started.

Comment: My server is running on my local machine. So network latency for 2 queries shouldn't be much. There is clear difference between the execution time taken in both the cases. you quoted isolation level doesn't depend on auto commit, my understanding is when there is a transaction there is a isolation level. Doesn't it applies to session transaction when I set autocommit=0?

Comment: Yes, it does, but you don't change the isolation level from the default one.

Comment: So You suggest on autocommit=0 isolation level is default(repeatable read)? If I never changed the session/global isolation level?

Comment: I don't have to suggest, you can check it with select @@session.tx_isolation, and yes, it doesn't lie.

Comment: Thanks. I am yet to find out what is cause of slowness of complete execution of queries(+set session+start transaction+commit) in first case. Isolation level is same so work done by innodb for keeping the isolation level is same in both case.